# Connecting VS code to PostgreSQL running on Windows Server 2019

Tags: database, postgresql, visual-studio-code, windows-server

I am running PostgreSQL on my Windows Server 2019. I already changed the settings in **postgresql.conf** to **listen_addresses = '*'**. I also changed the **pg_hba.conf** to **host    all     all     192.168.1/32        trust**. When I try to connect using VS code running on my laptop I keep getting a Failed to connect error. 
My question is do I put the IP address of my server in the "Server Name" section or do I put the 127.0.0.1:xxxxx

Here is what I am talking about, not sure what to put to make it work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the Microsoft extension ([ms-ossdata.vscode-postgresql](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-ossdata.vscode-postgresql&ssr=false#overview)) - there are a few extensions that allow you to work with PostgreSQL but the screenshot looks like the one from Microsoft.

In that case just enter the server IP (you will be asked for the port number later - I think it's the fifth prompt). You would only enter 127.0.0.1 into this field to connect to a server running on your local machine (or when connecting via an ssh tunnel but thats not the case here!).

If you are still having issues I would recommend installing the [Postgres](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) client tools (run the setup and uncheck everything except the "Command Line Tools"). You can then confirm that you can connect using [psql.exe](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) before adding the extra complexity of 3rd party tools (checking server firewall rules is generally a good first step).

Comment: That is correct, I am using the Microsoft postgreSQL extension for this. Thank your for clarifying. I did run it that way and I keep getting this error: "PostgreSQL: Failed to connect: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "192.168.1.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" I will have to run the psql.exe to narrow down where the issue is.